# How to read an object outside a PROMISE .then function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch, es6-promise

I'm trying to reach an object outside a PROMISE .then() method but when i'm calling the function outside the scope my object become undefined.

my app is a chrome extension.

the function -

```
function get_API (){
  let url = 'http://example.com'
  fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then (data => { 
        console.log(data)
        return data
      })
    }
```

Output is good and printing the json from the API url to the console.

but when trying to reach it outside the .then() scope with:

```
let x = get_API()
console.log(x)
```

the output is undefined

---

EDIT:
the answer provide bt Dusan Malusev is that i needed to add return before the fetch. now it is working.

working code:

```
function get_API (){
  return fetch('www.example.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then (data => { 
        console.log(data)
        return data
      })
      
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand promises and callbacks you should checkout this talk
[Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ). Javascript event loop at first runs all synchronous code, that means
`console.log` runs before any of your promise code, that is why x is `undefined`, callback inside `.then(...)` will run after all synchronous code and after all callbacks (there is difference between callbacks and promises)
You can think of promise like you have postponed something to run later.

`async => await` is just a syntactic sugar for promises, it makes our javascript look like synchronous code but it's asynchronous. Everything that i said for promises is still valid inside `async => await` (they are just promises)

```
async function asynFunction() {
   const x = await get_API();
   console.log(x);
}
```

this function is the same as:

```
function f() {
   get_API().then(data => {
        let x = data; 
        console.log(x));
   })
}
```

not as:

```
function f() {
   let x;
   get_API().then(data => x = data)
   console.log(x)
}
```

Resources for callbacks and promises:

[Async JS Crash Course - Callbacks, Promises, Async Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s)

[MDN Prmises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[MDN Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

JavaScript is not the same as other languages, you need to wrap your head around the event loop. and do everything "JavaScript Way".

Answer to your question:

```
   function get_API() {
       let url = "http://example.com";
       return fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              return data;
          });
   }
```

`fetch` function has two promises by default, first to get the response from the server, second you use to format the data. If you would like to use it like this

```
function f() {
   get_API().then(data => {
        let x = data; 
        console.log(x));
   })
}
```

your api function has to be changed

```
  function get_API() {
       let url = "http://example.com";
       return fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json());
   }
```

now your function returns a promise and you can use `.then` inside another function and get the data.

Comment: thank you. i tried both of your samples but the console goes empty (before their was 2 logs - one good and second endefined. now all empty)

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake, i was just trying to explain to you promises, not to solve the problem, will edit my post and show you the answer.

Comment: Go and checkout links that i provided, you will learn a lot from them and understand javascript, all quirks that you need when you develop application

Comment: yaiiiiiiiii - this is the answer. thank you so much

Comment: bro if you are still here can you tell me how to get the value outside the scope cause now when i call `let y = asynFunction()
console.log(y)
` i get in console Promise object

Comment: you cannot do that inside javascript. thats not how javascript works. If you have promise you have to use .then or await
Check the links i posted, you will learn a lot from them

Comment: you can get the value in a few ways
1. Self calling function
```js
(async () => {
  const y = await asynFunction();
  console.log(y);
})()
```

2. Inside another async function
```js
async function f() {
  const y = await asynFunction();
  console.log(y);
}
```
3. Using .then
```js
function f() {
  asynFunction().then(y => {
    console.log(y);
 })
}
```

Comment: Please go and learn promises and callbacks and event loop before you start using promises, they are now fundamentals of javascript. ```js fetch(...)``` is promise based, old school XmlHttpRequest is callback based, so you need to understand how they work

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise like this

```
function get_API() {
  let url = "http://example.com";
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
}
```

And then **await** for the response, in an **async** function

```
async function asynFunction() {
  const x = await get_API();
  console.log(x);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @re_search, the answer is correct so you must be doing something else which we don't see.

Comment: if the first log is empty, probably the response is empty, check that

Comment: copy-paste (just changing the url)- 


`function get_API (){
  let url = 'www.example.com'
  fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then (data => { 
        console.log(data)
        return data
      })
    }

async function asynFunction() { 
  const x = await get_API();
  console.log(x);
}`

Comment: check the response on the network tab on developer tools

Comment: @DavidLacedonia i checked and when calling it with the sync-await function the network not reaching tha API url but when just calling it with get_API() regular function it is

Comment: "not reaching" is not being fired? don't forget to call `asyncFunction()`

Comment: @DavidLacedonia you are right i didnt call it :( :( but now it is again undefined

Comment: can you paste the response you get on the network call? to identify the problem

Comment: Dusan Malusev find the problem. needed to add return before the fetch.  thank you very much for your help :)